# JAX-RPC webservice serialization issue on WAS6.1 test environment

Tags: soap, websphere-6.1, jax-rpc

I'm trying to pass Vector of complex objects as a result of a WS method. I'm following a JavaBeans scheme and all Collections are replaced by Vectors already, but I'm still getting a serialization exception WSWS3037E: Serialization cannot occur for [myclass]
How can I test if serialization really fails or this is WAS issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 6.1 it is recommended by IBM to use arrays instead of Vectors. Vectors are supported but their use is not recommended. Also, all of your classes in the Vector/array must implement Serializable.